# Python Currency Converter

Tags: python

The following code is a simple currency converter.  Everything works but the last if statement, which causes the code to break.  Whenever I put a number less than .25 in an if statement, it breaks the code.  I would greatly appreciate any input to why this is.  Thank you very much.

```
def currency_converter(amount):
        hundred = 0
        fifty = 0
        ten = 0
        five = 0
        one = 0
        quarter = 0
        dime = 0
        while amount > 0:
                if amount >= 100:
                        hundred+=1
                        amount-=100
                if 100 > amount >= 50:
                        fifty+=1
                        amount-=50
                if 50 > amount >= 10:
                        ten+=1
                        amount-=10
                if 10 > amount >= 5:
                        five+=1
                        amount-=5
                if 5 > amount >= 1:
                        one+=1
                        amount-=1
                if 1 > amount >= float(.25):
                        quarter+=1
                        amount-=float(.25)
                if float(.25) > amount >= float(.1):
                        dime+=1
                        amount-=float(.1)
        print(hundred, "Hundred-dollar bill")
        print(fifty, "Fifty-dollar bill")
        print(ten, "Ten-dollar bill")
        print(five, "Five-dollar bill")
        print(one, "One-dollar bill")
        print(quarter, "Quarter")      
        print(dime, "Dime")
currency_converter(5.6)
```

Comment: What do you mea by "breaks the code?"

Comment: Don't you need nickels and pennies?

Comment: You should multiply the input by 100 and cast to an integer to avoid float precision problems. That's assuming that there is no input with values less than a penny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def currency_converter(amount):
  amount = int(100*amount)
  hundred = (amount//10000)
  amount -= hundred*10000
  fifty = (amount//5000)
  amount -= fifty*5000
  ten = (amount//1000)
  amount -= ten*1000
  five = (amount//500)
  amount -= five*500
  one = (amount//100)
  amount -= one*100
  quarter = (amount//25)
  amount -= quarter*25
  dime = (amount//5)
  amount -= dime*5
  penny = amount
  return (hundred, fifty, ten, five, one, quarter, dime,penny)
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  That really helped.  Do you mind letting me know why the floats less than .25 caused a problem in my code? Thanks again.

Comment: @Lanie909 I'm not sure this is the problem you are referring to, but when you're value is < 0.1 (say 9 cents or 0.09), your loop will go forever without stopping. Your while condition should really be `while amount >= 0.1`. @alberto-o , wouldn't your function be better with divmod? Like: `quarter, amount = divmod(amount, 25)`  (I love divmod soooo much...)